# Hibernate mapping tables with many columns

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, relational-database

I'm working with grails and hibernate and need to map database table having many columns (over 50) to domain classes. What is the best way of doing this: one huge domain class or several smaller classes sharing same id of the table record?

The purpose of doing this is storing input data from big form which could potentially be done part by part (user can submit some parts of form using ajax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible I would suggest to split columns into logical groups and map these groups to different domain classes. Maybe you can reuse some of the domain classes later if they are generic enough (common classes like `Address`, etc).

Note that you can embed multiple domain classes into one table using the [embedded](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html) property.